# Django - Replicating the admin list_display

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

What's the easiest method to get list_display functionality in my main website (outside of the admin pages).

I have a group of elements I'd like to select and perform an action.  Any ideas?

Comment: The list_display option is to controls which columns appear in the change list table. What do you exactly want to implement?.

Answer (score 2):

An application called [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter) is by far the best and easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Object List](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list) from [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/).